# Laravel: model instance value is not quoted at method `save()`

Tags: laravel, database, laravel-8, quotes, quoting

I scrape data of the site https://news.ycombinator.com/news?p=1

Some title contain commas, eg.: **Lorinda Cherry, author of dc, bc, eqn has died**
So, when I make to save the model (as part of the Laravel CLI command) into DB there is an error.
The code:

```
  try {
            $news = new News; 
            $news->link =   $item['link']  ; 
            $news->title = $item['title'] ;
            $news->date = explode('T',  $item['date'] )[0];
            $news->points = $item['points'];         
            $news->save();
      } catch (Exception $e ){
                $this->error($e->getMessage());
      }
```

**Error**:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '
    763 ' for column 'points' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `news` (`link`, `title`, `date`, 
    `points`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (https://ncwit.org/profile/lorindacherry/, 
    Lorinda Cherry, author of dc, bc, eqn has died, 2022-02-15,
    763 , 2022-02-16 11:37:39, 2022-02-16 11:37:39))
```

Obviously the value **Lorinda Cherry, author of dc, bc, eqn has died** is ***not quoted*** at method `save()` as the Laravel model item and therefore **its content gets mixed with another query parameter**...

**Why is that in Laravel ?

How to fix ?**

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to save string in points column where column is integer type
Thanks

Comment: if the **title is without commas**, an integer value will match the **points** column

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$news->title = '\'' . $item['title'] . '\'';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in **Incorrect integer value**

So, you can cast the point value:

```
$news->points = (int) $item['points'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use **validation** to know your errors and on your code the
**request['points']** is not integer you are trying to save something that is not integer on your database  you should either change the data type on your database to string or you should submit integer data to your endpoint.
**before saving something to your database you should validate the data i highly recommend**

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
        'link'=>'required|url',
        'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'date' => 'required|date',
        'points'=>'required|numeric'
    ]);
News::create($validatedData);
```